# Deleting directories and files after uninstallation of LAMP

Tags: server, uninstall, lamp, delete

I want to start a fresh installation of LAMP. I went through several answers on how to remove/uninstall LAMP but the issue being that even after uninstallation there are still many PHP,MySQL and Apache folders and files in `etc`, `var`, `usr` folders.

How to uninstall LAMP completely such that all the files/folders created during installation are deleted when LAMP is uninstalled?

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
apt-get purge <packagename>
```

Will remove not only the packages, but the configuration files as well.